# How to analyze a system in nonthermal equilibrium?

Tags: density-matrix

In quantum information theory, density matrix is one of the main resource for analyzing a system.

I know in general how to obtain density matrix of a system but there is a case that still i dont know about it. And its when a system is not in thermal  equilibrium with environment.

How to obtain density matrix in this case?